Почему при изменение цены товара в CCatalogProductProvider она меняется только после многократных обновлений страницы?
Почему при изменение цены товара в CCatalogProductProvider она меняется только после многократных обновлений страницы? В методе getData, я меняю цену товара на свою, все бы норм, но меняется она после трех и более обновлений. Почему так происходит- я просто не пойму. При обновлении количества-цена обновляется, но как сделать, чтобы при переходе на страницу корзина обновлялась сразу? Буду рад любой подсказке.

Скорее всего, проблема в кэше.

Спасибо, сбрасывал кеш, пробывал в инкогнито но бесполезно

Кеширования есть несколько вариантов:

Пункт Автокеширование в панели управления, причем почему-то
выборочный сброс часто не помогает, только полный сброс всего кеша.
Кеширование инфоблока. Оно сбрасывается через фронт в режиме
редактирования - при наведении мышью появляется выпадающее меню с
шестеренкой. Ткнуть и выбрать Очистить кеш компонента.
Еще есть кеш сервера, заданный в htaccess
Еще в PHP коде инфоблока могут быть какие-то авторские функции
кеширования.

Если всё же это не кеш, то вы неполную информацию пишете.
